# WordPress - How To Remove Default WYSIWYG Field That Appears On All Posts / Pages Or Change It's Order

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if it is indeed possible to remove or re-order the default WYSIWYG field that is displayed in all posts and pages within the WP admin.  I mean the field that gets outputted to the page by using:

```
<?php the_content() ?>
```

Sometimes this is needed to create a more logical user experience so that stuff is edited within the admin in the same order as it appears within the actual site itself.

I know it can be argued that in some cases you can still keep the order by using this field for your first piece of content but sometimes that content is so small that it doesn't seem to make much sense.

However sometimes the first piece of content can not even utilise this area and I know some people just leave it blank but that feels untidy to me.

All time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

default WYSIWYG in Wordpress is TinyMCE and you can disable it with this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/disable-tinymce

This plugin disables the visual editor for all users across the whole site. You could also remove the wp-includes/js/tinymce/ directory

And if you want to totally remove this from your site - delete `<?php the_content() ?>` from all of your templates but I do not understand why it may be necessary

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not trying to disable TinyMCE or remove the tag from all of my templates.  I am trying to delete or change the order of that default field.  E.g. if you have a slider as the first piece of content on the page, the area to edit will fall beneath the default field.  Therefore to preserve the order of the flow of content within the admin compared to the website, you would have to leave that field blank.  If I could position the slider fields above it or remove it altogether, it will make more sense to the user.